# Busca por sub-strings Python 3.xx

Tags: python

Como faço para encontrar Ocorrências de Substring em uma string no Python. Preciso fazer na mão é essa minha dificuldade, tenho que percorrer a string e se achar duas ocorrências de substring iguais tenho que remover uma. Na saída é contado a quantidade de ocorrências das substrings e retorno as strings corretas.as string são todas minusculas e sem acento.

```
                 string= str(input('digite palavra:'))
                  for i in range(len(string)):  
                                x=string[-3:]
                                 y=string[-2:]
                                if string.find(x)and string.find(y):        
                                         a = string
                                          b = x or y
                                          for i in range(0,len(b)):
                                                   a =a.replace(b[i],"",1)
                                   Print( a)
```

Exemplo:

```
Aulaula - retira' ula' fica Aula
Indodo - retira 'do' fica indo
aa- retira o 'a' fica a
Estavatava- retira o 'tava' fica Estava
```

no meu codigo só consigo com a palalvra 'indodo
já com as outras fica(Auula, aa,Esravatava)

Comment: Parece me que quer dizer procurar substrings em palavras, caso contrário teria que retirar o `pr` de programar em pratica. E pelo aspeto também terá que ser pelo menos duas letras caso contrário cada palavra não podia ter letras repetidas. Clarifique tanto quanto possível o enunciado, e de preferência mostre o que já fez para o tentar resolver

Comment: Olá Isac, estou na luta com esse código, é isso mesmo  tenho que procurar uma substring em cada palavra, pode ser com 2 ou 3 letras ou mas, no exemplo Aulaula tem duas substrings(ula) com 3 letras, tenho que eliminar a segunda para a palavra ficar correta.

Answer (score 2):

Usando expressões regulares:

```
import re
str = input('digite palavra:')
for m in re.finditer(r"\b(\w+)+\1\b", str):
  str = str.replace(m.group(1) * str.count(m.group(1)), m.group(1), 1)
print(str)
```

Com o exemplo acima você terá algo como:

```
>> digite palavra: indodo estavatava
indo estava

>> digite palavra: indododododo
indo

>> digite palavra: aulaulaula
aula

>> digite palavra: estavatava
estava
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FlawedSpecializedSpecialist)

---

```
str = str(input('digite palavra:'))
words = [ str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:] ]
result = str
for w in words:
  if result.count(w) > 1:
    result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
print(result)
```

Com o exemplo acima você terá algo como:

```
>> digite palavra: indododododo
indo

>> digite palavra: aulaulaula
aula

>> digite palavra: estavatava
estava
```

Você pode adicionar mais posições na lista `words`.

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MatureWeeBetatest)

---

Levando em consideração o que temos aqui, você pode contar a palavra, exemplo:

```
>> str = 'aulaula'
>> a = str[-3:] # = ula
>> b = str[-2:] # = la
>> print(str.count(a), str.count(b))
2 2
```

Veja que no exemplo acima ele encontrou duas ocorrências de **la** e **ula**, agora crie a variável `c` e defina seu valor como a variável `a` e faça uma condição:

```
>> c = a if str.count(a) >= str.count(b) else b
```

A condição verifica se a quantidade de palavras de `a` é maior ou igual a de `b`, se sim, `c` continua igual a `a` se não `c` será igual a `b`.

Agora substituía o valor de `c` vezes a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas `c * str.count(c)` pelo valor do próprio `c`

```
>> result = str.replace(c * str.count(c), c, 1)
>> print(result)
'aula'
```

O código completo:

```
str = str(input('digite palavra:'))
a = str[-3:]
b = str[-2:]
c = a if str.count(a) >= str.count(b) else b
result = str.replace(c * str.count(c), c,1)
print(result)
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WideDullApplets), vale lembrar que não é 100% garantido.

Comment: OLÁ WMSOUSA, seu código funcionol para( Aulaula e indodo), mas eu tinha esquecido de colocar mas duas palavras que são ( Estavatava e aa), nessas o código retornou elas sem alteração, desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Veja novamente, esse segundo código. Você pode ir colocando as posições em `words`, para `aa` adicione `str[-1:]`

Comment: Olá amigo, refiz com o segundo código só não funcionou com aa, desde já agradeço sua ajuda

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/MatureWeeBetatest

Comment: Amigo VWMSOUSA, você é um mágico em programação, funcionou corretamente seu código, um dia chegarei nesse seu nível para poder ajudar outros programadores, obrigado amigo pela ajuda.