# Contar quantidades de trocas realizadas com replace em python

Tags: python

Preciso de uma ajuda no  código, preciso contar quantas trocas foram feitas na frase, vocês tem alguma ideia pra me passar.esse codigo é para retirar substrings repitidas que estão no final da frase, agora preciso contar quantas trocas foram feitas no "replace" do código na lista.

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
palavra = [str[-1:], str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
result = str
palavra_modificada = False
for w in palavra:
    if result.count(w) > 1:
        result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
        palavra_modificada = True

return palavra_modificada, result

lista1 = ['programaramar ee legalal','python ee showow','linguagemem de programacaocao']
aux2 = []
cont_palavras_modificadas = -1
for i in lista1:
aux1 = i.split()
for j in aux1:
    palavra_modificada, x = corrigePalavra(j)
    aux2.append(x)
    if palavra_modificada:
           cont_palavras_modificadas += 1
b = " ".join(aux2)
print(cont_palavras_modificadas, b)
```

Saida do meu código:

```
   2 programar e legal
   4 programar e legal python e show
   6 programar e legal python e show linguagem de programacao
```

Saida Correta:

```
  3  programar e legal
  2  python e show
  2  linguagem de programacao
```

ou seja 3 ocorrencias na primeira frase,2 na segunda e 2 na terceira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você também pode utilizar *Expressões Regulares*, como citei na [**resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291027/60376) dada em sua pergunta [**Busca por sub-strings Python 3.xx**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290947).

Para contar, faça o mesmo que já esta fazendo, só que em vez de incrementar, você apenas altera o valor para 1:

```
import re
def corrigePalavra(str):
  count = 0
  for m in re.finditer(r"(\w+)+\1", str):
    str = str.replace(m.group(1) * str.count(m.group(1)), m.group(1), 1)
    count = 1
  return count, str

linha = 'eu estavava indodo para aaaaaa aulaula'
total = 0;
resultado = [];
for palavra in linha.split():
  count, retorno = corrigePalavra(palavra)
  total += count
  resultado.append(retorno)

print(linha)
print(' '.join(resultado))
print('{} palavra(s) corrigida(s)'.format(total))
```

Veja [funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SadAgitatedActivecontent)

Answer (score 1):

Você incrementa o contador mas não faz nada com ele. Um jeito é retornar ele também:

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
    palavra = [str[-1:], str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
    result = str
    cont = 0
    for w in palavra:
        if result.count(w) > 1:
            result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
            cont += 1

    return cont, result

lista1 = 'estou indodo para a aulaula'
aux1 = lista1.split()
aux2 = []
cont_total = 0
for i in aux1:
    cont, x = corrigePalavra(i)
    cont_total += cont
    aux2.append(x)
print(aux1)
b = " ".join(aux2)
print(cont_total, b)  # 6 estou indo para a aula
```

Porém, assim ele conta o *número de letras* substituídas, e não o número de palavras afetadas. Podemos modificar um pouco o programa pra resolver isso:

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
    palavra = [str[-1:], str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
    result = str
    palavra_modificada = False
    for w in palavra:
        if result.count(w) > 1:
            result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
            palavra_modificada = True  # Se fizermos uma substituição, marcamos palavra_modificada como True

    return palavra_modificada, result

lista1 = 'estou indodo para a aulaula'
aux1 = lista1.split()
aux2 = []
cont_palavras_modificadas = 0

for i in aux1:

    palavra_modificada, x = corrigePalavra(i)
    if palavra_modificada:
        cont_palavras_modificadas += 1

    aux2.append(x)
print(aux1)
b = " ".join(aux2)
print(cont_palavras_modificadas, b)  # 3 estou indo para a aula
```

Agora temos a contagem de 3. Isso acontece porque o algoritmo é um pouco falho. Ele acha que fez uma substituição no "para" porque olha pro "a" e acha mais de dois "a"s na palavra. Um jeito de corrigir isso é levar em consideração só repetições de mais de uma letra:

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
    palavra = [str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
...
```

Agora o resultado sai como o esperado.

Como uma dica mais ampla, procure dar nomes mais descritivos às suas variáveis para dar mais clareza ao seu código, principalmente quando for o compartilhar com outras pessoas. `aux1` não fala nada sobre o que a lista deve representar, `lista1` sequer é uma lista e `palavra` também não é uma string, mas uma lista de fragmentos de string que não são palavras. Possíveis nomes melhores pra essas variáveis seriam, por exemplo, `palavras_isoladas`, `frase_original`, e `lista_substrings`.

Comment: Obrigado pedro  suas dicas vão me ajudar muito, muito obrigado, vou procurar atentar para palavras usadas sem sentido.

Comment: Pedro se eu alterar a str[-1:] não vou poder fazer na palavra por exemplo (aa) .

Comment: Por algum motivo o correto é inicial a variável `cont_palavras_modificadas` com seu valor negativo: `cont_palavras_modificadas = -1` pois `'estou indodo para a aulaula'` tem duas palavras a ser alteradas e não três.

Comment: Excelente wmsouza, deu certo sua dica, obrigado amigo.

Comment: @wmsouza o motivo é que ele conta letras repetidas em uma palavra, e portanto conta `para` como uma palavra substituida. Mesmo inicializando a variável como -1, se a frase muda pra "estou indodo para a aulaula para estudar" ele erra de novo porque agora conta "para" duas vezes.

Comment: Olá vmsouza, amigo como faço para realizar essas trocas numa lista tipo lista1 = ['programaramar ee legalal','python ee showow','linguagemem de programacaocao']